# What would be Magento 2 equivalent of Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')

Tags: magento

I have code in magento 1.9 version as follows :

```
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
->setSection($section)
->setWebsite(null)
->setStore(null)
->setGroups($groups)
->save();
```

What would be equivalent code in magento 2 ? Please someone guide .

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, there are multiple ways of storing values into the `config_data`.

**First Option**

You can use `\Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory` to save into the database.

```
protected $_configFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Factory $configFactory
) {
    $this->_configFactory = $configFactory;
}

$configData = [
    'section' => $section,
    'website' => null,
    'store' => null,
    'groups' => $groups
];

$configModel = $this->_configFactory->create(['data' => $configData]);
$configModel->save();
```

**Second Option**

In Magento 2, you can also use `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface` to store data in `core_config_date` table.

```
$this->configWriter->save(
    'general/country/default',
    'DE',
     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES, 
     0
);
```

**Third Option**

Use `\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $resourceConfig`

```
$this->_resourceConfig->saveConfig(
    'general/country/default',
    'DE',
     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES, 
     0
);
```

Comment: @Sohil does the above solutions make sense? If this is the answer to your question then you could upvote/accept